# CSS classes are not getting applied when assigned inside jQuery .attr()

Tags: jquery, css, attributes

I am manipulating the data-complete-text attribute of a link using jQuery. My code looks like this.

```
var complete =  _self.attr("data-complete-text");

_self.attr("data-complete-text","<span class='symbol-done-tick'></span><span class='acheived-text'>"+complete+"</span>");
```

That is I am assigning html spans to this attribute to get the desired effect and it works fine. I mean, the spans get inserted properly but the CSS classes which I have specified in these spans don't have any effect. I dunno why. Help me out.

Comment: You refer to "CSS classes" but you talk about modifying `data-*` attributes. `data-*` attributes are not "CSS classes", although you can style elements on the basis of `data-*` attributes (using attribute selectors rather than classes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to set the `data-complete-text` so that Bootstrap's [`Button`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons) will use it, after setting the `data-complete-text` attribute you have to set the state of the button as well:

```
_self.button('complete');
```

The documentation (such as it is) doesn't *say* it supports HTML there, but it seems to work in my test: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ajokox/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ajokox/2/edit)

HTML:

```
<button id="target" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-loading-text="Loading...">Original Text</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  // Get the button
  var _self = $("#target");

  // Set the attribute
  _self.attr("data-complete-text",
             "<span class='foo'>Complete</span>");

  // Wait for click
  _self.one("click", function() {

    _self.button('complete');
  });

});
```

In the above, the `foo` class on the `span` inside the `data-complete-text` works when you set the button state to `'complete'`.

Comment: If that is the case, How can I possibly use .html() or .append() here. Can you explain?

Comment: IS it possible to use html or append along with data-complete-text?

Comment: Sure, you can chain lots of jQuery operations. `_self.attr('data-complete-text', 'something').html("<span class=...>");`

Comment: My goal is to add that html to the attribute "data-complete-text".

Comment: @ArvinthShriram: I've done a live example, seems to work. Hope that helps.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Your live example is not working!

Comment: @ArvinthShriram: Yes, it is. I did just update it though, JSBin has gone all live and collaborative so maybe you caught it mid-edit (although I did do the Create Milestone thing to prevent that). Try again. I've tested it in Chrome and Firefox. Oh, and: You're welcome. (Hint: It never hurts to thank people for their time.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I dint really mean to sign off without thanking you. Thanks for your effort. I will try out the thing which you have posted.

Comment: @ArvinthShriram: No worries, hope that helps.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It helped big time. Nailed it! Kudos to your live example. It made things clear to me. Thanks a ton.